# How to Hide a Link With an Image or a Div

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, embed

I have an embedded presentations on my website with links going back to the presentation website, but I need to make it so that you can't click those links. I've read through the embed code and there's no way to disable it there, so I want to put something over it that will block the links from being clicked on. Can I put a transparent div over the links or a transparent image. I've tried both and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you share some code please?

Comment: @3boll I would but I don't really think it would be helpful. I'm using a free drag and drop editor because this is for a group project so the code is ghetto as hell. It's a horrible mess to try and read. I'll try and make a jsfiddle with a similar premise.

Comment: why cant you try seting the `href` to `#` and style to `display:none;` instead of this dirty trick.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh there's not an <a> or an href to mess with or I would delete them. It's flash stuff.

Comment: Perhaps adding a div dynamically with js would help (although not on js-disabled browsers ofc.)? Never tried though

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the link of the screen with `position:-9999em`

Answer (score 0):

Should have clarified that the presentations were flash content!

To disable external links in flash you have to change two properties in the embed tag. Change `allowscriptaccess` to `never` and set `allownetworking` to `internal`. After many hours I finally found that.